# I have an error with my Unity game In App Purchases

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, google-play, game-development

> Unity IAP: Unity In-App Purchasing requires Unity Gaming Services to have been initialized before use.
>
> - Find out how to initialize Unity Gaming Services by following the documentation https://docs.unity.com/ugs-overview/services-core-api.html#InitializationExample
>   or download the 06 Initialize Gaming Services sample from Package Manager > In-App Purchasing > Samples.
> - If you are using the codeless API, you may want to enable the enable Unity Gaming Services automatic initialization by checking the Automatically initialize Unity Gaming Services checkbox at the bottom of the IAP Catalog window
>   UnityEngine.Purchasing.UnityPurchasing:Initialize (UnityEngine.Purchasing.IStoreListener,UnityEngine.Purchasing.ConfigurationBuilder)

I am getting these errors, how can I fix them? How can I fix this and stop it from happening?  My unity IAP doesn't take any datas from the user right?  I mean last time that I checked, when I purchased IAP in my TestFlight, it just pop a simple page and says confirm.  It doesn't take any data like credit or debit information, so I don't have to report this to Apple Store or Play Store data privacy?

Answer (score 0):

[Initialize Unity Gaming Services](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.purchasing@4.2/manual/UnityIAPInitializeUnityGamingServices.html)

```
public class InitializeUnityServices : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string environment = "production";

    async void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            var options = new InitializationOptions()
                .SetEnvironmentName(environment);

            await UnityServices.InitializeAsync(options);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // An error occurred during services initialization.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/32347845)